# Absolute worksheet reference in excel cell formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet

I have a list in `Sheet3` populated using contents of a column in `Sheet1`. It uses simple cell referencing to do so. However sometimes I move entire rows from `Sheet1` to `Sheet2` when the task in that row is completed. So once moved, I no longer want the list in `Sheet3` to list the item that I've just moved to `Sheet2`. However, when I move the cells from `Sheet1` to `Sheet2`, excel automatically changes the reference from `Sheet1` to `Sheet2` in the formula in `Sheet3` hence failing my objective.

How can I use absolute reference to my worksheet so that when I move cells, the formulas remains unchanged? I know such a feature exists in Libreoffice where you can simply use a $ symbol before the sheet name. But that doesn't work in Excel.

My formula in row 1 column 1 of `Sheet3` is:

```
=Sheet1!C6
```

And this is copied down to all the rows below making it `Sheet1!C7`, `Sheet1!C8` and so on in the rows below.

Comment: This happens when you cut paste (because you are moving cells without loosing their reference in the formula), not when copy paste. So, you may want to copy paste the row from sheet1 to sheet2 and then delete it from sheet1. This is layman's solution. There can be better one though.

Comment: @NareshBhople Thanks, yes I meant to say cut-paste. Unfortunately due to my usage scenario, copy-pasting and then deleting from the first sheet may not be possible all the time. I'll need some other solution.

Comment: Then you can use like indirect/ offset formula to refer to the cells. Then even if you cut paste it to other range, reference to the original cells address in the formula won't change.

Comment: @NareshBhople I don't understand how I can use either of those functions in my case. Could you take a look at my formula and help me change it? I've edited my question and added the formula.

Comment: If you enter formula as `=Indirect("Sheet1!C6") and then move Sheet1!C6 the reference in the formula won't change. So, the result will be 0, as you have moved the cell. This is basic idea. You can copy such formula with dynamic range. There are many web resources/videos on dynamic range with indirect and offset.

Comment: For example [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GUClkvJ7Gag)

Comment: to take @NareshBhople's suggestion further you could extend INDIRECT to `=INDIRECT("Sheet1!C"&ROW())` so that you don't have to manually update the row element of your source cell.

Comment: @mitch-NZ Thank you, that worked like a charm. Exactly what I wanted!

Comment: @NareshBhople Thanks! I had tried indirect before, but it was not working before the cell format was set to Text. But anyways your comments were really helpful. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @mitch-Nz and @Naresh Bhope for the solution which worked:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!C"&ROW())
```

I simply used this in `Sheet3` and now if I move rows to a different worksheet, the reference will stay as Sheet1 itself in sheet3.